# Timer - without alarm and wakeup support?

Tags: android, time

I have strange issue with alarms, which seems not to be supported.
I can use rtc0 timer, but not alarms.
Trying to do

```
root@w812a_kk:/ # busybox rtcwake -s 10
rtcwake: /dev/rtc0 not enabled for wakeup events
1|root@w812a_kk:/ #
```

then trying to compile a code which does timer, and alarm, I get invalid argument on

```
ioctl(fd, RTC_AIE_ON, 0);
```

I also see that wakeup entry is missing:

```
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/dev
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/date
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/name
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/time
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/power
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/device
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/subsystem
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/hctosys
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/max_user_freq
/sys/devices/platform/mt-rtc/rtc/rtc0/uevent
/sys/class/rtc/rtc0
```

How can I enable alarms ?

Thanks
Ran